# Julia does not update its packages

Tags: julia

I installed `DifferentialEquations` by using:

```
Pkg.add("DifferentialEquations")
```

Then I used the below line to check the version:

```
Pkg.status("DifferentialEquations")
```

It returns 1.0.0 while, it must be 4.0.0.

I tried `Pkg.update()` or `Pkg.update("DifferentialEquations)`. However, the version is still 1.0.0 and re-installing Julia did not help neither.

What can be done to update the `DifferentialEqautions` package?

The version of Julia is 0.6.2.

**Edit**

This time I not only uninstalled Julia, but I also deleted its folder in `appdata`. After installing Julia again and adding the package, now it is up to date.

Comment: What version julia are you running? This could be limiting the version of DifferentialEquations.

Comment: The version of Julia is 0.62.

Comment: When you run `Pkg.status`, does it say that any of your package versions are pinned (on any package?)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
Pkg.pin("DifferentialEquations",v"4.0.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force `Pkg` to find a solution by giving an explicit version.

For example, going from version 5 to version 6 of the `DifferentialEquations` package:

```
(TestProject) pkg> status
    Status `/tmp/TestProject/Project.toml`
  [0c46a032] DifferentialEquations v5.0.0

(TestProject) pkg> add DifferentialEquations@6.0.0
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `/tmp/TestProject/Project.toml`
  [0c46a032] ↑ DifferentialEquations v5.0.0 ⇒ v6.0.0
  Updating `/tmp/TestProject/Manifest.toml`
  [1520ce14] - AbstractTrees v0.2.1
  [79e6a3ab] - Adapt v1.0.0
  [4fba245c] ↓ ArrayInterface v2.3.1 ⇒ v0.1.1
  [9e28174c] - BinDeps v1.0.0
...

(TestProject) pkg> status
    Status `/tmp/TestProject/Project.toml`
  [0c46a032] DifferentialEquations v6.0.0
```

The equivalent API syntax:

```
julia> import Pkg
julia> Pkg.add(Pkg.PackageSpec(; name="DifferentialEquations", version=v"6.0.0"))
```